# AxiosError message: 'Request failed with status code 500'

Tags: node.js

I tried a test payment from stripe and I got this error code:

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"

I expected for stripe to succeed in test payment but this error suffices.

the code for payment is:

//code

```
const Pay = () => {
    const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null)

    const onToken = (token) =>{

        setStripeToken(token)
    }

useEffect(()=>{
    const makeRequest = async ()=>{
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/checkout/payment" , {
                tokenId: stripeToken.id,
                amount: 2000,
            },)
            console.log(res.data)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
    stripeToken && makeRequest()
}, [stripeToken])
```

The endpoint Payment code is:
//code

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post('/payment', (req, res) => {
  stripe.charges.create(
    {
      source: req.body.tokenId,
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: "usd",
    },
    (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
      if (stripeErr) {
        res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with the api getting the request. Read more about the error code 500 here: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/runtime/500-internal-server-error-0

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post the text itself.

Comment: And now what does your server code at that endpoint look like and what gets logged on the server?